# Gmail Inboxes and Java

Tags: java, gmail

My java application listen to Gmail inbox using IMAP Protocol but it's not stable at all.

Sometimes it works fine and sometimes not
many different exceptions appear like:

- Connection dropped by server.
- FolderClosedException
- Too many simultaneous connections
  and list goes on...

is there another practical way to listen to gmail inboxes even in another technologies like nodesjs or php or even **paid service**?

Comment: any ideas here please!